# SendinBlue, guzzle: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, sendinblue

I'm working on a project where I need to send transactional emails to my clients.

The following error appears when sending the request. I use SendinBlue V3 SDK.

```
Exception when calling TransactionalEmailsApi->sendTransacEmail: Connection refused for URI
https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email
```

My method code:

```
$config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', 'secret');
$apiInstance = new TransactionalEmailsApi(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://[secret].online'
    ]),
    $config
);
$sendSmtpEmail = new SendSmtpEmail();
$sendSmtpEmail['to'] = [
    [
        'email' => $parameters['mail'],
        'name' => $parameters['user'],
    ]
];
$sendSmtpEmail['templateId'] = 3;
$sendSmtpEmail['params'] = [
    'FIRSTNAME' => $parameters['user'],
    'LASTNAME' => $parameters['verification_code'],
];

try {
    $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacEmail($sendSmtpEmail);
    print_r($result);
} catch (ConnectException $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling TransactionalEmailsApi->sendTransacEmail: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you configure correctly your https client with Guzzle ?
If not connecting, then you can check if any other exceptions are thrown. You have a great inventory of them in the Guzzle documentation : https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#exceptions

```
. \RuntimeException
└── TransferException (implements GuzzleException)
    ├── ConnectException (implements NetworkExceptionInterface)
    └── RequestException
        ├── BadResponseException
        │   ├── ServerException
        │   └── ClientException
        └── TooManyRedirectsException
```

In your case, it is a `ConnectException`.
Try to get more information about it.

Why `ConnectException` are thrown usually ?
When you can not connect.

When you can not connect ? When you are not using correct endpoint url, have not configured your HTTP client to use HTTPS protocol, not using the endpoint accordingly to its specs you'll find inside official documentation.

You can look the official tutorial too : https://developers.sendinblue.com/docs/send-a-transactional-email

You can use the github.com sendinblue official repository too with the php api well described : https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library

Comment: I added [protocols https] to the guzzle client, still same error.

Comment: Issue is still there. I also added an extra curl support on tls.1.2 but even that didn't work. With postman it work with production server it doesn't, we have a normal lets encrypt ssl cert.

Comment: Ok. Which php extensions are enabled in your dev environment and not in your production environment ? Did you check the required php extensions/modules for using the sendmail PHP API v3  features in your production env ? ext/json, and others : are they enabled ?

Comment: Did your install Guzzle on your production server ? Sometimes some people deploy only the webapplication, and forget to install/update/refresh some dependencies using composer, or the new versions of the dependencies have some breaking changes.

Comment: If guzzle wasnt installed, you didnt got the exception

Comment: @BendaThierry.com I don't use sendmail php. It is just a simple guzzle http request against sendinblue. How hard is it to solve this. The problem is still there. I also update composer so that is not the problem. Other things works perfectly.

Comment: @peterhillie It is not hard to solve that kind of problem. Compare your local php configuration with your production php config. Configure a third environment where you can run some integration testing with your pre-production code.
When I have talked about "sendmail PHP API v3", it is your SendInBlue php code using the REST API and not the sendmail local program.

Answer (score 1):

Document says:
**Relay access has been refused**
Authentication may have failed: check your API key,

Please also be sure that your 587 port is open.

run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Even when I use the SendinBlue SMTP as well?

Comment: You can read more about here: https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000188150-Troubleshooting-issues-with-the-SMTP I found the answer from this documentation.

Comment: I understand but it is not a problem with the SMTP, it is a problem with guzzle, I open my 587 port etc. restart and flush everything, again same guzzle error.

Comment: I had the same problem. It is not because the SMTP is working because we send it by an api. And the sendinblue api will handle it on its own.

Comment: Yes same like mine.